# Await function working in class component but not in functional component

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I am migrating my React Class component to a React functional component. Below piece of code working fine with class  but not with function: `fetchAsset` async function doesn't return proper data. Because of that, the whole following logic is compromised. I suspect the `await` to have a role in this.

Below are the code for specific method concerned in both Class and Functional  components:

**Class component method:**

```js
navigateToNextScreen = async asset => {
  this.setStateWrapper({
    navigating: true
  })
  try {
    await this.props.actions.selectedAsset.cleanSelectedAsset()
    await
    this.props.actions.salesConfirmation.cleanSalesConfirmation()
  } catch (err) {
    throw Error(
      `Error cleaning selected asset or sales confirmation: /n${err}`
    )
  }
  try {
    await this.props.actions.selectedAsset.fetchAsset(asset.listing_id)
  } catch (err) {
    throw Error(`Error fetching selected asset: /n${err}`)
  }
  try {
    this.loadRecordingFee()
    if (this.props.store.selectedAsset.receipt_of_funds) {
      this.loadInitialFundsEntry()
    }
    this.calculateRefundOwed()
  } catch (err) {
    throw Error(`Error loading data from API: /n${err}`)
  }
  console.log('navigateToNextScreen33', this.props.store.selectedAsset)
  console.log(
    'navigateToNextScreen11',
    !this.props.store.selectedAsset.bidder_info?.party_id
  )
  console.log(
    'navigateToNextScreen22',
    isSoldButNotClosed(this.props.store.selectedAsset.status)
  )
  // If non-registered bidder won auction, go to bidder registration
  if (
    !this.props.store.selectedAsset.bidder_info?.party_id &&
    isSoldButNotClosed(this.props.store.selectedAsset.status)
  ) {
    await this.props.actions.registration.storeRegistrationSource(
      screens.SALES_CONFIRMATION_MENU_TITLE
    )
    showModal({
      screen: screens.BIDDER_REGISTRATION,
      title: screens.BIDDER_REGISTRATION_TITLE,
      passProps: {
        fromScreen: screens.SALES_CONFIRMATION_MENU,
        toScreen: screens.BIDDER_REGISTRATION,
        startTime: new Date(),
        salesConfirmationMenuComponentId: this.props.componentId,
      },
    })
  } else {
    goToScreen(
      this.props.componentId,
      screens.SALES_CONFIRMATION_REVIEW,
      screens.SALES_CONFIRMATION_REVIEW_TITLE, {
        startTime: new Date(),
        fromScreen: screens.SALES_CONFIRMATION_MENU,
        toScreen: screens.SALES_CONFIRMATION_REVIEW,
      }
    )
  }
}
```

**Functional component function:**

```js
const navigateToNextScreen = useCallback(async asset => {
  setStateWithCallback(true, setNavigating, null)
  try {
    await props.actions.selectedAsset.cleanSelectedAsset()
    await props.actions.salesConfirmation.cleanSalesConfirmation()
  } catch (err) {
    throw Error(
      `Error cleaning selected asset or sales confirmation: /n${err}`
    )
  }
  try {
    await props.actions.selectedAsset.fetchAsset(asset.listing_id)
  } catch (err) {
    throw Error(`Error fetching selected asset: /n${err}`)
  }
  try {
    loadRecordingFee()
    if (props.store.selectedAsset.receipt_of_funds) {
      loadInitialFundsEntry()
    }
    calculateRefundOwed()
  } catch (err) {
    throw Error(`Error loading data from API: /n${err}`)
  }
  console.log('navigateToNextScreen33', props.store.selectedAsset)
  console.log(
    'navigateToNextScreen11',
    !props.store.selectedAsset.bidder_info?.party_id
  )
  console.log(
    'navigateToNextScreen22',
    isSoldButNotClosed(props.store.selectedAsset.status)
  )
  // If non-registered bidder won auction, go to bidder registration
  if (
    !props.store.selectedAsset.bidder_info?.party_id &&
    isSoldButNotClosed(props.store.selectedAsset.status)
  ) {
    await props.actions.registration.storeRegistrationSource(
      screens.SALES_CONFIRMATION_MENU_TITLE
    )
    showModal({
      screen: screens.BIDDER_REGISTRATION,
      title: screens.BIDDER_REGISTRATION_TITLE,
      passProps: {
        fromScreen: screens.SALES_CONFIRMATION_MENU,
        toScreen: screens.BIDDER_REGISTRATION,
        startTime: new Date(),
        salesConfirmationMenuComponentId: props.componentId,
      },
    })
  } else {
    console.log('navigateToNextScreen55')
    goToScreen(
      props.componentId,
      screens.SALES_CONFIRMATION_REVIEW,
      screens.SALES_CONFIRMATION_REVIEW_TITLE, {
        startTime: new Date(),
        fromScreen: screens.SALES_CONFIRMATION_MENU,
        toScreen: screens.SALES_CONFIRMATION_REVIEW,
      }
    )
  }
}, [props.store.selectedAsset])
```

Actions for it as below:

```js
export const getAsset = (fetchedAsset, listingId) => ({
  type: types.GET_ASSET,
  payload: {
    ...fetchedAsset,
    listing_id: listingId,
  },
})

export const fetchAsset = listingId => {
  return async dispatch => {
    const fetchedAsset = await assetProvider.getTrusteeContract(listingId)
    await dispatch(getAsset(fetchedAsset, listingId))
  }
}

export const cleanSelectedAsset = () => ({
  type: types.CLEAN_SELECTED_ASSET,
})
```

Comment: There's a lot of code here. Could you please narrow it down to the relevant parts? Please also include the code for `fetchAsset` since it doesn't appear to return anything. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with a focus on the **minimal**

Comment: @Phil Edited my question. I have added actions as well. Data is not getting dispatched properly from fetchAsset it seems to be

Comment: In that function component no props is pass to the function

Comment: Does the function work if you don't use `useCallback`?

Comment: Props are passed. The functional component is connected to redux. The main file is so long so just I have added that particular function only.

Comment: Without useCallback also it is not working

Comment: The problem with this code is since fetchAsset not returning data for the first time. So, the 'if' condition gets failed and my screen redirects to the screen which presents in the else block. If I get back again and try to navigate then it works properly. Same scenario working perfectly fine in class based component

Comment: Also, it's missing the `connect` of the component in both cases. 
also agreed, there is too much code to get a relevant answer.

Comment: cleanSelectedAsset() and cleanSalesConfirmation() works as expected?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a problem due to stale data issue. So please check for stale data. Since you are using `useCallback` there are chances that you might not have added dependencies properly. So also check that.